# How can I apply a background size to a background color?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images and on hover, it will display a text that also has a background color to it. The issue i'm facing right now is the background color is only filling to the text. What I want it to do is instead span across the entire image with a set height to it as well. Is this possible?

```css
#pictures {
  line-height: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#pictures li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.hoverelement:hover .imageText {
  background-color: rgba(235, 242, 238, .8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pictures">

  <li>
    <div style="position: relative">
      <a href="/" class="hoverelement"><img src="1.jpg" height="250" width="250">
        <p class="imageText">TEXT</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

example of what i mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can center the text with flexbox but you need to make sure the text takes up the full space of its relative parent.

When you set top, right, bottom and left to 0 for an absolutely positioned element, it will take up the full space of its relative parent without the need to define width/height.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The above 3 rules for your text element will center it horizontally and vertically.

Remaining issues - due to the way your width is set 33% on the `li` and the image has its own width, you will see strange behaviour when you hover because the 33% might be more/less than the 250 on the image. I don't know what you are trying to do with this so I did not edit those css rules and I am sure you can figure it out from here

```css
#pictures {
  line-height: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#pictures li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageText {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hoverelement:hover .imageText {
  background-color: rgba(235, 242, 238, .8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pictures">

  <li>
    <div style="position: relative">
      <a href="/" class="hoverelement"><img src="1.jpg" height="250" width="250">
        <p class="imageText">TEXT</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just set the image w x h to show the example in the snippet. But isn't the top/right/bottom/left also affecting the size of the background color? From what I'm getting at least, now it's filling the entire image with the background color on hover

Comment: @Brandon isn't that what you wanted? if not, please clarify, you can easily remove the top/bottom if you want it to span across 100% or you can define width/height. I have adjusted the code to do 100% width, for the height, you could either set a fixed number or just set padding like you are doing and when the text gets larger(2 lines or more) the height of the element will get larger naturally

Comment: i just wanted it to be like a little banner going across the image. I edited my original post with a terrible picture as a reference. But your update is achieving that now. One thing I noticed (and it might just be me) is that the width overflows past the image on each side a little bit. I thought maybe changing withe width from 100% would help fix that but it appears to only shorten the background color from the right hand side. Would you have any ideas about that?

Comment: @Brandon as I mentioned in my answer, your image width and `li` width do not match up in most cases. If I were you, I would not even need that div, I would put the relative on the anchor and make it a block element. The width still needs to be fixed but you said it was to show the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify width and height for your **absolute** positioned element otherwise it will have the smallest possible dimensions limited by it's **inner content** in your case text `TEXT`.

What you really want is a paragraph with 100% width and height and center it's content instead, like so:

```css
#pictures li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
#pictures li .image-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#pictures li .image-text p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
#pictures li .image-text:hover {
  background-color: rgba(235, 242, 238, .8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pictures">
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="hoverelement">
      <img src="1.jpg" height="250" width="250">
      <div class="image-text"><p>TEXT</p></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instead of filling the entire thing though, can i get the width to stay 100% but make the height be adjustable? I don't want to completely cover the image with the background color, just a little sliver of it on hover

Comment: @Brandon Yes, you can, just do not set height. You can also position element at bottom (instead of top), the height will be automatically calculated according to box-sizing. I highly advise you to learn about positioning and box-sizing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#pictures li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37.5%; /* (100% - height) / 2 */
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: rgba(235, 242, 238, .8);
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: -10px; /* (-1 * padding of the li) */
  padding: 0px;
  display: none; /* hide */
}

.imageText:before { /* vertically centers the text within the grey bar */
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hoverelement:hover .imageText {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pictures">

  <li>
    <div style="position: relative">
      <a href="/" class="hoverelement"><img src="https://picsum.photos/250" height="250" width="250">
        <p class="imageText">TEXT</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: So this fills the entire image up. Is there a way i can instead choose how much it fills? I do want the width to remain at 100% but the height to come way down so it's like a little banner that goes across the image on hover

Comment: @Brandon something like that?

Comment: Just set the height and top to how much you want.

Comment: Yeah that's more like it. Its overflowing on the right hand side for me and i lost the center text but I think that's my side doing it so i gotta figure that part out now. But at least i got that background color now!

Comment: @Brandon I've added the calculation you need for the top. And added some css to vertically align the text within the grey overlay too.